# save some lists in txt files using for loop

Tags: python

```
import itertools
for x in range(0,6):
    w1 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(w1_out[:,:,0,x]))
    w1_out = ['{:.20f}'.format(i) for i in w1]
    sis_dir = "w1_out_{}.txt".format(x)
    np.savetxt(sis_dir, w1_out, delimiter=',',fmt='%s')
```

I need to copy separately some parts of an 4D array into a list and then save it in .txt
but if I use a loop for:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: `w1_out` seems to be a list, not a 4D array. That's why `w1_out[:,:,0,x]` is not a valid call.

Comment: If I do it manually without loop, naming variables as w1,w2,..ecc, and  w1_out, w2_out, ecc.. and putting 1,2,3 where there's a x, it works. It works also if I use "for x in range(0,0)", just one iteration works. but I need to do it in a loop because the number of iterations is high

Comment: I get it, I'm just telling you why is your error popping! Just use a real 4D array instead of list if you want to use this kind of indexing

Comment: I converted the list in an Array... Solved, thank you